# How can I host many identical java web applications?

Tags: java, hosting, glassfish-3, load-balancing, cluster-computing

I have a problem. I need to host many (tens, hundreds) of small identical JAVA web applications that have different loads during one time. I want to use Glassfish V3. Do I need to use a load balancer and clusters or something else? Advise where can I find information about similar problems and their solutions...

Comment: why do you need tens of the same app?

Comment: seconded, why do you need tens of the same app ? why not just one app, automatically multi-threaded by the webserver ?

Comment: How would you separate the many instances pr URL?  Please edit your question with more information.

Comment: It depends on *why* you need tens or hundreds of these apps - clustering, cloud computing, a grid, or something else...

Comment: 1) Each of these applications is ownership of my clients, I will be host they.
2) Each of these apps will be use one's own database and domain, have separate contents and etc.
3) yes, I want to create separate instance for each application. I know that I can hosted approximately 10-20 apps per machine, but I as well know that these apps will be active at different times. So if I need to have 100 applications, I am in the simplest case, can use the 5-10 servers each of which will be host 10-20 applications, but more time each server will be idle - is not productive.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to host many (tens, hundreds) of small identical JAVA web applications that have different loads during one time.

For hundreds of webapps, you will very likely need more than one app server instance. But this sounds odd to be honest.

> I want to use Glassfish V3. Do I need to use a load balancer and clusters or something else?

Right now, GlassFish v3 offers only [basic clustering support](https://glassfish.java.net/public/comparing_v2_and_v3.html) using mod_jk (i.e. no load balancer plugin, no centralized admin, no high availibility). If you are interested, have a look at [this note](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/amyroh/archive/2009/06/running_glassfi.html) that describes the configuration steps of GFv3 and [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/).

For centralized admin and clustering, you'll have to wait for GlassFish 3.1 (see the [GlassFish Roadmap Community Update slides](http://glassfish.org/roadmap)).

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Gigaspaces](http://www.gigaspaces.com/).  I have seen it used in conjunction with [Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/display/MULE/Home) for a somewhat similar project.  ESBs tend to be overkill in my opinion, but it sounds like you have quite the task to conquer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Based on your requirements, you cannot do load balancing since the load is predetermined by which client the request is for. Each request has to go to the app handling that client, so it cannot be distributed outside the set of apps dedicated to that client.
2. You can use multi-threading. you could set up the configuration so that different threads handle different clients. However, it might be better to simply have a server that can handle requests from different clients. Based on the client sent with the request, it would be dispatched to a different database etc.